# How to change the value of a string in Kotlin after it has already been initialised?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm trying to code this problem: Initialise a String as “Hello, Kotlin” and change its value to null. Now print the length of the String using safe call and non-null assertion operator.

I know how to initialise a string with null value, but don't know how to set it as null after it's been already initialised with a different string value.

Comment: Do you wanna print the length before or after setting the string to null? Because after, you can not print the length would return null, even with a safe-call.

Answer (score 0):

To set null in a variable it needs to be declared as nullbable.

```
fun main() {
    var srt: String? = "Hello, Kotlin"
    
    println(srt)
    
    srt = null
    
    println(srt)
}
```